# Get Value of Hidden Field in MVC With JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, typeahead.js

I'm Having trouble access the hidden field PartsId.  The output HTML from this gives the field part_PartsId.  How would I get the value of it from my typeAhead function?  My JavaScript is firing, but only seems to return the typeahead object information that fired it.

```
<div class="input-group col-lg-3 scrollable-dropdown-menu">
         <div class="input-group-addon">@Html.LabelFor(a => part.Part)</div>
              @Html.HiddenFor(a => part.PartsId)
              @Html.EditorFor(a => part.Part, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control typeahead" } })
    </div>
```

My JavaScript File

```
    $(".typeahead").on("typeahead:selected", typeAhead)
    .on("typeahead:autocompleted", typeAhead);
    function typeAhead(obj, suggestion) {
         var test = $(this).parent().find('partidClass').first();
    }
```

UPDATE: It seemed relevant to show the MVC Generated HTML

```
 <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon"><label>Part</label></div>
      <input class="partidClass"type="hidden" value="12345" />
      <input class="form-control typeahead text-box single-line" type="text" />
 </div>
```

Comment: It's `.find('#part_PartsId')`, but your code suggests your generating controls in a loop which means you generating duplicate `id` attributes - remove the `id` and use a class name instead

Comment: Isnt the id your looking for PartsId? So `$(this).parent().find('#PartsId').first();`

Comment: I haven't done this before. Yes it's in a loop, I thought that duplicate IDs would cause a problem. Is there a different way I should be selecting them?  Wouldn't Class have the same problem as I wouldn't know which hidden field I was going to be working with because it's within the loop

Comment: Not only is your `foreach` loop generating invalid html, its also generating duplicate `name` attributes which will never allow you to correctly 2-way bind to your model (refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943) for more detail). All you need to do is add a a class name for the hidden element (say `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Parts[i].PartsId, new { @class = "partid" })` and use `var test = $(this).parent().find('.partid');`

Comment: You knew so much with so little code to go by, very impressive!  I have made those changes, and I do see the difference, however my JavaScript still doesn't find the hiddenfield.var test = $(this).parent().find(".partidClass");
        alert(test.val()); gets me an undefined error.  So my original problem still exists.

Comment: Because `$(this)` is not your object. - `$(".typeahead").on("typeahead:selected, typeahead:autocompleted", function() { var test = $(this).parent().find('.partid'); });`

Comment: Changing my Javascript to this still gave me an undefined.  I added the HTML output from the MVC hoping that might help

Comment: I have created this simple [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qcp83x8o/) based on your edit to show you how it works - just enter a value in one of the textboxes, tab out and it will alert the value of the associated hidden input.

Comment: Excellent, that worked for me, can you submit it as an answer?